# Access struct property in Go

Tags: go, struct

Now I’ve struct which implements this interface like following

```
type MyRunner struct {
    path string
}

func (r MyRunner) soSomthing(newPath string) error {
    run(path)
    return nil
}
```

Now I want to create the object and I got error 
implicit assignment of unexported field 'path' in MyRunner literal

This is how I do it

```
&run.MyRunnter{”a/b/c/“}
```

is there a way to do it without the New keyword in Go ?

Comment: You're trying to access (set, get, doesn't matter) an unexported field from another package. The compiler won't let you do it, even if you're trying to use a composite literal to initialize it.

Comment: @Marc - ok but im trying to initate object why its not working , I require it...

Comment: Because this is the same as saying `run.MyRunner{path:"a/b/c"}`, you're still accessing the unexported field from another package. If you want your object initialized, you can have a helper in the same package:  `func NewRunner(p string) *Runner { return &Runner{path: p} }`, or just export the field.

Comment: @Marc - thanks a lot, which way is prefered?

Comment: It ultimately depends on whether this field is supposed to be used from outside the package or not. If you don't care, make it exported.

Comment: @marc, thanks a lot, I will use your suggestion , btw how should I initiate your suggestion `func NewRunner(p string) *Runner { return &Runner{path: p} }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go every field starting with lower case letter is considered private and is accessible only within its package.  Simply change the name to `Path`.

```
type MyRunner struct {
    Path string
}
```

This rule applies to other identifiers in Go: type names, function names. See [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) on documenation.

If you don't want to make the field public. Write a funciton that will act as a constructor.

```
type MyRunner struct {
    path string
}

func NewMyRunner(path string) *MyRunner {
    return &MyRunner{path}
}
```

Example from standard library [container.list.New](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#New)

Comment: ok thanks 1+ since I need to use it as constructor field it should be “public” , am I right? or should I use accesor methods ?